# Sublime Text 2 - Disable line highlight when the margin is clicked

Tags: sublimetext2

When I click on the line numbers in the margin, it highlights the entire line and moves the cursor to the beginning of the following line (presumably so that you can quickly copy that line to the clipboard).

Is there any way to disable this behaviour and have the cursor simply jump to the beginning of the line that was clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X, hold down <kbd>⌥</kbd> (Option key, or Alt) while clicking on the margin. On Windows and presumably Linux, you can click using the middle mouse button.

If you want to make this the default behavior for mouse button 1 (the left button), create a new file with JSON syntax and the following contents:

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1",
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
    }
]
```

Save it in your `Packages/User` directory as `Default (your_OS).sublime-mousemap`, where `your_OS` is one of `OSX`, `Windows`, or `Linux`. You can find the `Packages` directory by clicking on **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**.

### ***Warning!***

This will make your left mouse button act like the center mouse button - you **won't** be able to double-click to select words, and click-drag events will select columns instead of lines. There is no way to isolate this behavior to just the margin, unfortunately.

Comment: This didn't work for me, unfortunately.  I tried using the Ctrl key, Windows key, and Alt key, and various combinations thereof, but none seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @Novark - sorry, I was using VMs running on OS X. I'm now on native Win8, and middle-clicking on the margin does what you're trying to do. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  Out of curiosity, are you aware of any way to make this the default click behaviour?

Comment: That's a shame that there's no native way to do it within Sublime Text 2 itself.  I do appreciate you taking the time to find a workaround though!  Thanks!